# I would like to better understand this code to save in cache with expiration date

Tags: javascript, angular, caching

Guys I have this code that saves my products in cache, I would like to better understand how it works,

```
  getItemById(id) {
  // return this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}item/getById/${id}`);
  return  
 this.cacheS.getOrSetCache(`StoreService_getItemById_${id}_${this.layout.emp.id}`,  
 this.http.get(`${environment.API_URL}item/getById/${id}`), 300000);
 }


getOrSetCache(key: string, request: Observable<any>, msToExpire = 300000): Observable<any> {
let cache: any = {};

cache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));

return (cache?.data && (cache?.exp > Date.now())) ?
  of(cache.data) :
  request.pipe(tap(v => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify({data: v, exp: (Date.now() + msToExpire)}));
  }));
}
```

My question is more about how it manages to save in cache with an expiration date, and when the date expires, make the request again

This code works, but I couldn't understand how, is there any other better way to cache with expiration date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call `getOrSetCache`, you pass `msToExpire` to arguments. `Date.now()` returns the current time. If this element is not in the cache, you make a request and after receive data, you save in to ls, and set time to expire as `date.now() + msToExpire`. And in the next call of this function you compare `exp` from your save element with current time `Date.now()`.

For example the cache is empty, and you call `getOrSetCache` at **17:00**. And let's imagine that the `msToExpire` = **30 min**. Since the cache is empty, we make a request and save the data to the cache `exp: (Date.now() + msToExpire)`  = **17:00 + 30 min = 17:30**. Now, if call your function at **17:20** o'clock, this condition `cache?.data && (cache?.exp > Date.now()))` returns true, cause **17:30 > 17:20** and you will receive data from cache. But if you call it at **17:31**, condition will return false, and it make new request and rewrite data in cache with new timestamp